# how to generate an array of 0s and 1s of size 41003 and number of 1s should be 100 only?

Tags: python

I want to generate an array of size 41003 containing 0s and 1s. but the number of 1s should be 100. how to do this in python?

I tried to generate using

```
np.random.randint(2, size=41003)
```

but the number of 1s is not 100.

Comment: show your code trials with error trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a list with n=41003 zeros. Then use `random.sample(range(n), k=100)` to generate 100 non repeated random indices on that list. 
 Finally, set to 1 the values in the list with those indices.

```py
from random import sample

n = 41003
values = [0] * n
for i in sample(range(0, n), k=100):
    values[i] = 1

print(values.count(1)) # 100
```